# Excel Macro to create different font and add hyperlinks to part of text in single cell in word document

Tags: excel

I really got stuck with some problem when I am creating word document (with particular format) through excel macro.
I have a button in excel. fter clicking on it a word document will open. In word document text and multiple table will be there. Number of row and column are different in different. I had able to create the same. Now the problem is I have to make different font size and color in same cell for different part of text in the cell. Also I have to create hyperlink in part of text in a cell (not whole cell contain) which will connect to a lotus notes database.
For example I am sending a cell contain of my requirement (different line's Values will come from different cell of excel)

==========================================================

**Initiating  Unit**: 
Project Name

New SDLC Process

Impl Date:

Budget:   (Lx)

% Budget Spent:$765765

% Duration Complete:

Prj Sponsor: tuitiyu

IT Delivery: iyiuyoo

PM: khkjhk

## Detailed Status:

Can anyone please help me to come out with some solution, how to do the same?
Also please advise if there is any resource available who can help us if we face any issue to develop our current project? If anyone have any supporting document please send.

Thanks in advance.
Sukanta

Comment: please show us your current code, what you have already built and tried. As a first stab, see [this answer from brettdj](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717030/in-excel-have-to-search-for-specific-string-in-cell-and-apply-style-to-that-part/9717470#9717470) that will help you

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to have a .dot or .dotx template with all the styles and formatting in place and then create a document from the template and just copy the text from your excel file. Your template does contains all the text formatting you dont need to do in the code.

Comment: can you tell me more about dotx? can i have my data in one place and the styling template in another place?

Comment: Another example here http://vbadud.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/update-word-document-with-excel.html

Comment: About Word templates http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/overview-RZ010223218.aspx?section=1

Comment: thank you! im sorry i thought it was an excel thing. i thought that you can have plain data in one file and the formatting in another file for specifically excel not word